# Wait until a value in a map becomes available in Go

Tags: go, mutex, wait

I have a program where I basically have three scenarios - set value for a key, get value if it's there, or wait until the value for a given key becomes available. My original idea - create a new type with a `map[string]interface{}` - where "persisted" values are stored. Besides that, for waiting on a value, I planned on using a `map[string](chan struct{})`. When a `Set()` method is invoked, I would write to that channel and anyone waiting on it would know the value is there.

I don't know the keys in advance - they're random. I'm not sure how to correctly implement the `Wait()` method.

```golang
type Map struct {
    sync.Mutex

    m    map[string]interface{}
    wait map[string]chan (struct{})
}


func (m *Map) Set(key string, value interface{}) {
    m.ensureWaitChan(key)

    m.Lock()
    defer m.Unlock()

    m.m[key] = value

    // Signal to all waiting.
    m.wait[key] <- struct{}{}
}


func (m *Map) Wait(key string) interface{} {
    m.ensureWaitChan(key)

    m.Lock()
    
    value, ok := m.m[key]
    if ok {
        m.Unlock()
        return value
    }

    m.Unlock()
    // <------ Unlocked state where something might happen.
    <-m.wait[key]

    value := m.m[key]

    return value    
}

// If the channel does not exist for those waiting - create it.
func (m *Map) ensureWaitChan(key string) {
    m.Lock()
    defer m.Unlock()

    _, ok := m.wait[key]
    if ok {
        return
    }

    m.wait[key] = make(chan struct{}, 100)
}
```

The problem is - there's a race condition in `Wait()` - after I release the mutex, and before I start listening on a channel for incoming value.

What would be the best way to handle this? Open to any other suggestions on how to implement this, I believe there must be a better way to do this. I would refrain from polling the value at fixed intervals or anything like that.

Comment: Avoiding the race is simple, get the channel before unlocking, then lock the map again when getting the value. The real problem is that you are always going to have time-of-check-to-time-of-use bugs in this scenario, because the new value could have been changed again immediately after it's read. Are you trying to implement a message queue? Perhaps since channels are native it Go, pass the actual values through the channel rather than via the map?

Comment: I'm not concerned with the changed value, because I'll always want to use the first value received. Any further updates I don't really care about. I guess it is something like a simple message queue - have the ability to receive `n` items for a key, and have the ability for someone to wait until a value becomes available. However for the sake of the value, only the first one received matters.

Comment: Channels aren't required. The `sync` package has other features including condition variable support which can be used to address your use case. I've added an answer explaining how to use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is a mix between a synchronized map and a message broker. We can do this by leveraging the channels for communication as well as  synchronization, so that subscribers can receive the messages as soon as they are published if they are not yet in the cache.

```
type Map struct {
    sync.Mutex

    m    map[string]any
    subs map[string][]chan any
}

func (m *Map) Set(key string, value any) {
    m.Lock()
    defer m.Unlock()

    m.m[key] = value

    // Send the new value to all waiting subscribers of the key
    for _, sub := range m.subs[key] {
        sub <- value
    }
    delete(m.subs, key)
}

func (m *Map) Wait(key string) any {
    m.Lock()
    // Unlock cannot be deferred so we can unblock Set() while waiting

    value, ok := m.m[key]
    if ok {
        m.Unlock()
        return value
    }

    // if there is no value yet, subscribe to any new values for this key
    ch := make(chan any)
    m.subs[key] = append(m.subs[key], ch)
    m.Unlock()

    return <-ch
}
```

Because subscribers must unlock the map mutex while they wait, they cannot safely access new messages added to the map. We send the new value directly to all subscribers over their own channel so that we don't need to add more synchronization within `Set` to ensure that all subscribers are satisfied before unlocking the map itself. Unlocking the map early would allow subscribers to read it directly, but would also allow new values to be inserted in the meantime causing inconsistent results.

A running version, also including a generic `Map` implementation with type parameters: https://go.dev/play/p/AN7VRSPdGmO

Comment: Awesome! This looks perfect! I had the impression I was looking from the wrong angle. Side quest: If I were to implement a `Wait` that has a time limit, what would be your go-to choice? With the current implementation, one option I can think of is to have the channel buffered (size 1, just so that the setter does not block) and a `time.Ticker`, and have them in a `select`.. Do you think that's polluting the abstraction a bit?

Comment: @Aero, no, you don't want a `time.Ticker`, you want to select on something with a specific lifetime, like a single call to `time.After`. You could also supply a `context.Context` so that the caller can chose how it's canceled: https://go.dev/play/p/nPkkxLfp66u. You may then want to return an error or bool to check for timeout; or maybe instead always return a buffered channel containing a value so the callers can select, there are a number of ways to structure the API

Answer (score 0):

This uses a condition variable, and `context.Context` for `Wait` cancellation.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type Map struct {
    mu   sync.Mutex
    cond *sync.Cond
    m    map[string]interface{}
}

func (d *Map) Set(a string, b interface{}) {
    d.mu.Lock()
    defer d.mu.Unlock()
    d.m[a] = b
    d.cond.Broadcast()
}

func (d *Map) Get(a string) interface{} {
    d.mu.Lock()
    defer d.mu.Unlock()
    return d.m[a]
}

func (d *Map) WaitContext(ctx context.Context, a string) interface{} {
    quit := make(chan struct{})
    defer close(quit)
    var done bool
    go func() {
        select {
        case <-quit:
        case <-ctx.Done():
            d.mu.Lock()
            done = true
            d.cond.Broadcast()
            d.mu.Unlock()
        }
    }()
    d.mu.Lock()
    defer d.mu.Unlock()
    for !done {
        if b, ok := d.m[a]; ok {
            return b
        }
        d.cond.Wait()
    }
    return nil
}

func (d *Map) Wait(a string) interface{} {
    return d.WaitContext(context.Background(), a)
}

func main() {
    d := &Map{}
    d.m = make(map[string]interface{})
    d.cond = sync.NewCond(&d.mu)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        fmt.Println("waited and got c=", d.Wait("c"))
        wg.Done()
    }()

    d.Set("a", "apple")
    d.Set("b", "banana")
    fmt.Println("b=", d.Get("b"))
    fmt.Println("a=", d.Get("a"))
    fmt.Println("c=", d.Get("c"))
    d.Set("c", "cherry")
    fmt.Println("c=", d.Get("c"))
    wg.Wait()

    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        fmt.Println("waited and got d=", d.WaitContext(ctx, "d"))
        wg.Done()
    }()
    cancel()
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: I agree a `sync.Cond` fits really well for the example code (it's actually a really good example of how to use `sync.Cond`, which is hard to understand sometimes). I stuck with channels because almost every case where you want a `Wait` function will eventually want the ability to timeout.

Comment: I've added an explanation for how to cancel waits in this model. This is basic, but captures the core approach: record a cancel and then signal it is time to notice it.

Comment: Yup, but if you want individual timeouts (which is the more common API) and to ensure that no additional `Set` calls can be interleaved between clients completing blocked `Wait` calls (which is required for data consistency), you need to track each client. You end up with with tracking channels anyway, which means the Cond is no longer really necessary.

Comment: Fair. Rewritten to use `context.Context` to control cancellation by the client.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of sending `struct{}{}` to the channel, you could just close the channel. All reads from channel after that would be non-blocking.
This also solves a problem, your code currently has: if multiple goroutines are waiting on the same value, only one would get the signal.

You should also check whether the channel has already been closed, since closing the channel twice woud cause panic. You can do that by non-blocking read from channel with select statement with default case.

Comment: Since you have exclusive lock, no different gouroutine can close any channels in the map in the meantime.

Comment: You do have an exclusive lock. Channel would be closed only in the `Set` function. The function locks the whole `Map` object and unlocks it only after it returns. On the other hand, function `Wait` doesn't need a lock.

Comment: Yes, the locking would always need to ensure only one closer could ever close the channel. I think there's still probably a better pattern to ensure the channel gets closed once rather than setting up what looks like a bug, like just removing the channel from the wait map before closing. (removing my first comment since it's technically possible, to avoid confusion with the general case ;))